# Remove Checkbox From ListView SugarCRM/SuiteCRM

Tags: php, sugarcrm, suitecrm

I want to know how I can remove a checkbox from the ListView of the Contracts module if the status of Contract equals "Signed."

I tried the suggestion via this [link](https://techgurusblog.wordpress.com/tag/remove-checkbox-from-list-view/) by adding a condition like:
[Details of Manipulation](https://suitecrm.com/forum/suitecrm-7-0-discussion/6835-remove-checkbox-from-list-view).

However, nothing happened.

Comment: did u try to repair and rebuild?

Comment: Thank u for ur replay , concerning the quick repair , yes i did it ,but all checkboxes r removed , whereas I want to remove or disable just the signed contracts

Comment: Hi @soukaina idrissi can you post your code so I can check, it is better if you can show what had you done so far

Comment: By marking an answer as "accepted" you gain points also. Karl Hill's answer worked for me for example.

Answer (score 1):

1) Create file **custom/modules/AOS_Contracts/views/view.list.php:**

```
<?php

class AOS_ContractsViewList extends ViewList
{
    function AOS_ContractsViewList()
    {
        parent::ViewList();
    }

    function listViewProcess()
    {
        $this->processSearchForm();
        $this->lv->searchColumns = $this->searchForm->searchColumns;

        if (!$this->headers)
            return;
        if (empty($_REQUEST['search_form_only']) || $_REQUEST['search_form_only'] == false) {
            $this->lv->ss->assign("SEARCH", true);
            $this->lv->setup($this->seed, 'custom/modules/AOS_Contracts/tpls/ListViewAOS_Contracts.tpl', $this->where, $this->params);
            echo $this->lv->display();
        }
    }
}
```

2) Copy **modules/include/ListView/ListViewGeneric.tpl** to **custom/modules/AOS_Contracts/tpls/ListViewAOS_Contracts.tpl**

3) Change the lines:

```
{if !$is_admin && is_admin_for_user && $rowData.IS_ADMIN==1}
    <input type='checkbox' disabled="disabled" class='checkbox' value='{$rowData.ID}'>
{else}
    <input title="{sugar_translate label='LBL_SELECT_THIS_ROW_TITLE'}"
        onclick='sListView.check_item(this, document.MassUpdate)' type='checkbox'
        class='checkbox' name='mass[]' value='{$rowData.ID}'>
{/if}
```

to:

```
{if !$is_admin && is_admin_for_user && $rowData.IS_ADMIN==1}
    <input type='checkbox' disabled="disabled" class='checkbox' value='{$rowData.ID}'>
{else}
    {if $pageData.bean.moduleDir == 'AOS_Contracts' && $rowData.STATUS == 'Signed'}
    {else}
        <input title="{sugar_translate label='LBL_SELECT_THIS_ROW_TITLE'}"
            onclick='sListView.check_item(this, document.MassUpdate)' type='checkbox'
            class='checkbox' name='mass[]' value='{$rowData.ID}'>
   {/if}
{/if}
```

4) Do a Repair/Rebuild.

Comment: "AOS_Contracts" for SuiteCRM & "Contracts" for SugarCRM.

Comment: Thank you! Worked like a charm

Answer (score 0):

SugarCRM version 9
Create the PHP file recordlist.php and add:

```
$viewdefs['<MODULE>']['base']['view']['recordlist']['selection']['isSearchAndSelectAction'] = false;
```